# Installing Epsilon IDE using P2 director

Tags: eclipse-emf, p2

We intend to run a large set of EUnit tests using the antrunner application in CI/CD for experimentation.

For this, we need to implement a linux container that has the current P2 IDE installed in it.

We would like to use the P2 director to perform that installation.

What is the call to the P2 director to install the full Epsilon IDE, including binaries on Ubuntu 20?

You can assume that the instance has Java 11 OpenJDK installed.

Answer (score 0):

The P2 repository of the latest Epsilon release is `http://download.eclipse.org/epsilon/updates/2.2/`

You should be able to retrieve the IDs of all IUs in the repo as follows

```
./eclipse -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director \
   -repository http://download.eclipse.org/epsilon/updates/2.2/ -list
```

Comment: Thanks. That operation does provide the IUs for epsilon, but unfortunately this is insufficient to set up the solution, as the dependency information in the features is missing. The set is also too large, as we would like to use only the top-level dependencies. It will require some work with P2 QL to find out what this actually is. Once we have a full list I will post an answer here.